# Site on two different servers

Tags: server, synchronization

Im considering taking web server from China to reduce site loading times from China/China users. Problem is, how to sync/keep same data between two sites? When editing content in the site it should update these changes to site in China server.

Server is running Linux, Apache and MySQL. Website is using WordPress.

FYI I'm already using CDN and site loading speed is still too long from China.

Comment: You need to provide more information in order to receive a helpful answer. A manual solution will inevitably depend on what operating system you're using, and an out of the box solution will depend on what platform you're using.

Comment: Added more info. Any help/thoughts?

Comment: I'm writing an answer now. Stay posted.

Comment: OK the answer I was writing got ridiculously long...too long for StackOverflow. However, I do work as a freelance programmer and if you'd like I can help you with this project? It sounds interesting. Otherwise I can send you an email containing my answer?

Answer (score 0):

### Basically your solution would need to...

- Copy the entire contents of your http'd directory from the main server to the Chinese server.
- Copy the entire contents of your MySQL database from the main server to the Chinese server.
- Perform these tasks at a regular interval without manual intervention.

I can guide you to references that will help with each task and sometimes can show you a quick example. However, if you want to get it to work and especially if you want to optimize the process, you're going to have to look through the references yourself.

If I didn't do it this way this answer would get even more horrendously long that it already is.

### Before we start you should remember...

**Thing 0 - Please Try Not to be Intimidated by the Length of this Answer**

I know I've written a lot, perhaps more than I should have, but I guarantee you are capable of implementing this in no more than a day. I have tried to be thorough but that does not mean that what I'm describing is particularly complicated.

**Thing 1 - Shutdown your Chinese Server During Transfer**

This transfer of data is going to make your Chinese server unusable while it's in progress, as you might have guessed. You need to make sure that you're Chinese server is not operational during the transfer. Otherwise the server might have only partial data available which could cause problems for both client and server, particularly in relation to MySQL.

**Thing 2 - Use Compression as much as You Can**

As time consuming as compression and decompression can be for large amounts of data, believe me it is nothing compared to the time you will waste sending the uncompressed data to China. Network usage, not processor time, is really going to be the limiting factor in getting the transfer done quickly. Try to send compressed files whenever possible.

**Thing 3 - Try to Use Checksums**

Sending all your data, particularly in compressed format, will leave it vulnerable to corruption in transit. Whenever you send a file I encourage you to use some kind of checksum on the data to verify that it has not been corrupted. For brevity I will not be showing you how to do this but I'm sure you're smart enough to figure out how to pepper in some verification.

In case you're not familiar with checksums, [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) about them is pretty straight forward. The most commonly used are the [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), but both of those are somewhat collision prone. I would recommend the [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) (also called SHA-256/512) or the very new [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3).

### Copying your Http'd Directory to the Chinese Server

As far as I know (and I could be wrong) there is no built in way to transfer files from one Apache server to another...so you're going to have to write your own script for this.

You're also going to need to have two separate scripts: one for the main server and one for the Chinese server. Here's a breakdown of what each script needs to do.

**On your main server...**

1. Log in as you're Apache server's user. ([Reference for switching users](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su).)
2. zip/gzip/tar.gz your http'd directory's contents. ([Reference for zip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip). [Reference for gzip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip). [Reference for tar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar).)
3. `scp` (secure copy) the compressed file to your Chinese server. *Make sure to copy it to the username that Apache runs under.* ([Reference for scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp).)
4. Delete the compressed file.
5. Initiate the Chinese server's script (this will be discussed later).

You will likely be using a shell script for all of this, so I hope you're familiar with the terminal. A simple example would look like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

## First I'll define some variables to explain this better.

APACHE_USER="whatever your Apache server's username is (usually it's www-data)";
WWW_DIR="your http'd directory relative to ~ (usually it's /var/www)";
CHINA_HOST="the host name/IP address of your Chinese server"
CHINA_USER="Apache's username on the Chinese server";
CHINA_PWD="Apache's user password on the Chinese server";
CHINA_HOME="the home directory of the Apache user on your Chinese server";

## Now to the real scripting. I will be using zip for compression.

su - "$APACHE_USER";
zip -r copy.zip "$WWW_DIR";
scp copy.zip "$CHINA_USER@$CHINA_HOST:$CHINA_HOME" < echo $CHINA_PWD;
rm copy.zip;

## Then you initiate the next step of the process.
## Like I said this will be covered later.
```

**On your Chinese server...**

1. Log in as the Apache user.
2. Delete the content of the http'd directory (probably /var/www relative to ~).
3. Decompress the scp'd file (this will change depending on how you compressed it).
4. Copy the decompressed directory to the http'd directory (this step is unnecessary if you choose to compress with zip).
5. Deleted the compressed, scp'd file.
6. Notify main server to continue next step (again, will be discussed later).

This is pretty straight forward and I don't think you need another example for this part.

### Copying the MySQL Database Contents

You can find a good reference for how to do this in [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html) from the MySQL website. Basically copying database contents is a built in feature. **Try to make use of the compression options!**

### Performing these Tasks at Regular Intervals without Manual Intervention

Ok this is where things get kind of complicated.

The first thing you need to know is how to schedule tasks at regular intervals on Linux. This is done with a command line tool called `crontab`. You can see good examples for setting up cron jobs in [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/), and the [full crontab documentation here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab).

However what will take more skill than just scheduling the job at regular intervals will be synchronizing the data transfer. If you simply set one server to send data at a certain time and the other to receive it at a certain time, you will get many bugs. Be sure of that.

My recommendation would be to **create a socket in the Chinese server that listens for instructions from the main server.**

This can be done in a variety of languages. Because you're using Linux I would recommend doing this in C, but it can be done in almost any language including Bash.

A full example would be too much but basically this will be the flow of what you have to do.

1. Socket in China listens for connections.
2. Cron job in main server connects to China socket.
3. Main server authenticates itself.
4. Chinese server stops Apache, stops accepting requests.
5. Chinese server acknowledges authentication approved.
6. Main server `scp`'s website contents to Chinese server.
7. Main server tells Chinese server that `scp` is complete.
8. Chinese server replaces Apache's http'd directory's contents with the data that has been `scp`'d.
9. Chinese server announces success to main server.
10. Main server copies MySQL data.
11. Main server tells Chinese server process is complete.
12. Chinese server resumes Apache service.
13. Chinese server notify's main server that service is resumed.
14. Socket is closed.
15. Chinese server goes back to listening for connection from main server.

### I hope this helps!